# Fibonacci sequence calculator seems correct but can't find similar code online. Is there something wrong?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I made a simple Fibonacci sequence calculator for the first 22 terms:

```py
i=1
n=0
while i<=20000:
    i = i + n
    n = i - n
    print(i)
```

Looks like the result is correct

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
```

but I can't seem to find similar code anywhere online. I think that's a big red flag. Can someone tell me what is wrong here? Is this inefficient code?

Answer (score 8):

No, that code is fine. The probable reason you can't find similar code online is that it's unusual to use the subtraction operator in Fibonacci, which is a purely additive function, `tn = tn-2 + tn-1`.

It works, of course, since addition/subtraction is both commutative and associative, meaning that order and grouping of terms is unimportant:

```
i = i + n  # iNew = iOld + nOld

n = i - n  # nNew = (iNew)        - nOld
           #      = (iOld + nOld) - nOld
           #      = iOld + (nOld  - nOld)
           #      = iOld + (0)
           #      = iOld
```

Use of subtraction allows you to bypass needing a third variable, which would be something like this in a lesser language than Python:

```
nextN = i + n
i = n
n = nextN
```

In Python, you don't actually *need* that since you can use tuple assignment such as:

```
(n, i) = (i, n + i)
```

With that, *everything* on the right of the `=` is evaluated before *any* assignments to the left.

Answer (score 5):

It's an unusual way to do it, but it's correct.  Your lines:

```
i = i + n
n = i - n
```

are the same as doing:

```
new_i = i + n
n = i
i = new_i
```

or,

```
i, n = i + n, i
```

which would be the usual way in Python.